# How to Change the color of the text of the selected index in picker view in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to Change the color of the text of the selected index in picker view in iOS Swift?[image: As shown in the image , this is a Picker view (ScreenShot) and at the particular index (Selected Index) the Color of the text is changed to red , How to achieve this in iOS Swift?]

As shown in the image , this is a Picker view (ScreenShot) and at the particular index (Selected Index) the Color of the text is changed to red , How to achieve this in iOS Swift?

Thanks in Advance!!